# Connecting Shiny Movie gallery example with my own cvs file

Tags: r, shiny

I have read now the stackoverflow Q&A for several hours on various days and have also seen the latest specific Shiny debugging video from the [Shiny developer conference](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/) (Jonathan McPherson):

Now the problem looks simple to me, but I went through lots of checks, revisions of the naming conventions and thought of various hypotheses: Making column titles starting with capital letters, calling the initial file similar to the template, renaming the column titles, ...

I like the interactive scatter plots from the Movie Gallery and would like to reproduce it with my own records, located in a `cvs` file, which I uploaded in my RStudio session with the name `all_flexitime`, which I understand now is not enough.

How do I connect or integrate my `cvs` file into the given template? I have renamed all necessary fields, I believe. The error I am getting says:

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) :
>     object 'Flexileave2015' not found

`Flexileave2015` is, I believe, the first variable the server file is looking for to produce the scatter plot, but since the file needs to be found somewhere in the server file, it cannot find it there. I can see it in my Studio.

Can somebody confirm my understanding and possibly help, please.

My `all_flexitime` data frame is made of the following columns titles:

```
"Number", "First", "Last", "Contract", "Grade", "Flexileave2015", "Certifiedsickleave2015", "Uncertifiedsickleave2015", "Daysnotrecorded2015", "Excess2015".
```

My server.R is:

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

if (FALSE) library(RSQLite)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

# Filter staff, returning a data frame
flexitimes <- reactive({
# Due to dplyr issue #318, we need temp variables for input values
flexileave2015 <- input$flexileave2015
certifiedsickleave2015 <- input$certifiedsickleave2015
uncertifiedsickleave2015 <- input$uncertifiedsickleave2015
daysnotrecorded2015 <- input$daysnotrecorded2015
excess2015 <- input$excess2015

# Apply filters
m <- all_flexitimes %>%
  filter(
    Flexileave2015 >= flexileave2015,
    Excess2015 >= excess2015,
    Certifiedsickleave2015 >= certifiedsickleave2015,
    Uncertifiedsickleave2015 >= uncertifiedsickleave2015,
    Daysnotrecorded2015 >= daysnotrecorded2015

  ) %>%
arrange(Flexileave2015)

# Optional: filter by Contract
if (input$contract != "All") {
  contract <- paste0("%", input$contract, "%")
  m <- m %>% filter(Contract %like% contract)
}
# Optional: filter by Grade
if (input$grade != "All") {
  grade <- paste0("%", input$grade, "%")
  m <- m %>% filter(Grade %like% grade)
}

# Optional: filter by Number
if (!is.null(input$number) && input$number != "") {
  number <- paste0("%", input$number, "%")
  m <- m %>% filter(Number %like% number)
}

# Optional: filter by Last Name
if (!is.null(input$last) && input$last != "") {
  last <- paste0("%", input$last, "%")
  m <- m %>% filter(Last %like% last)
}
m <- as.data.frame(m)
m
})

# Function for generating tooltip text
flexitime_tooltip <- function(x) {
if (is.null(x)) return(NULL)
if (is.null(x$Number)) return(NULL)

# Pick out the staff with this Number
all_flexitimes <- isolate(flexitimes())
flexitime <- all_flexitimes[all_flexitimes$Number == x$Number, ]

paste0("<b>", flexitime$First, flexitime$Last, "</b><br>",
  flexitime$Grade, "<br>",
  flexitime$Contract
  )
}

# A reactive expression with the ggvis plot
vis <- reactive({
# Lables for axes
xvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$xvar]
yvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$yvar]

# Normally we could do something like props(x = ~BoxOffice, y = ~Reviews),
# but since the inputs are strings, we need to do a little more work.
xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$xvar))
yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))

flexitimes %>%
  ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
  layer_points(size := 50, size.hover := 200,
    fillOpacity := 0.2, fillOpacity.hover := 0.5,
    key := ~ Number) %>%
  add_tooltip(flexitime_tooltip, "hover") %>%
  add_axis("x", title = xvar_name) %>%
  add_axis("y", title = yvar_name) %>%
  set_options(width = 500, height = 500)
})

vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")

output$n_flexitimes <- renderText({ nrow(flexitimes()) })
})
```

The ui.R file is the following:

```
library(ggvis)

# For dropdown menu
actionLink <- function(inputId, ...) {
tags$a(href='javascript:void',
     id=inputId,
     class='action-button',
     ...)
}

shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Overview of Flexitime usage"),
fluidRow(
column(3,
  wellPanel(
    h4("Filter"),
    sliderInput("flexileave2015", "Flexileave 2015", 0, 14, 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("certifiedsickleave2015", "Certified sickleave 2015", 0,    230, 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("uncertifiedsickleave2015", "Uncertified sickleave 2015", 0, 13, 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("daysnotrecorded2015", "Days not recorded 2015", 0, 110, 0, step = 10),
    sliderInput("excess2015", "Excess 2015", -100, 1500, 0, step = 50),

    selectInput("contract", "Contract",
      c("All", "Temporary Agent", "Contract Agent", "National Expert", "Interim")),

    selectInput("grade", "Grade",
                c("All", "AD05","AD06","AD07","AD08","AD09", "AD10","AD11",  "AD12","AD13",              "AD14","AD15","AST01","AST02","AST03","AST04","AST05","AST06","AST07",
                  "AST08","AST09","AST10","FGII.04","FGII.05","FGII.06","FGIII.08","FGIII.09","FGIII.10",
                  "FGIV.13","FGIV.14","FGIV.16","FGIV.18","SNE")),

    textInput("number", "SAP Personnelnumber"),
    textInput("last", "Initial of Last Name")
  ),
  wellPanel(
    selectInput("xvar", "X-axis variable", axis_vars, selected = "Flexileave2015"),
    selectInput("yvar", "Y-axis variable", axis_vars, selected = "Uncertifiedsickleave2015"),
  tags$small(paste0(
    "Note: AD and AST are Temporary agent grades.",
    " FG are Contract agent grades.",
    " SNE is the only National expert grade.",
    " Interims should not have an FG grade."
  ))
)
),
column(9,
  ggvisOutput("plot1"),
  wellPanel(
    span("Number of staff members selected:",
      textOutput("n_flexitimes")
    )
  )
)
)
))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got external help for my shiny app, so I am posting how I sorted the problems in the end:

1. There was a spelling mistake for the all_flexitime data set, I changed it to be all_flexitimes.
2. In the preparatory work file (the one where I created the original database), I have made sure that the variables are read as characters and not as factors:

   all_flexitimes$Grade <- as.character(all_flexitimes$Grade)
   all_flexitimes$Contract <- as.character(all_flexitimes$Contract)
   all_flexitimes$First <- as.character(all_flexitimes$First)
   all_flexitimes$Last <- as.character(all_flexitimes$Last)
3. I have saved the all_flexitimes file into an .RData file via the following command, while I was in the RStudio working environment:

   saveRDS(all_flexitimes, "all_flexitimes.RData")
4. In the global.R file I have added at the end the following line, so that the database can be read:

   all_flexitimes <- readRDS("all_flexitimes.Rdata")
5. In the ui.file I used the following, as this was the safer option, as it avoids any misspelling:

   selectInput("contract", "Contract",
         c("All", sort(unique(all_flexitimes$Contract)))),

   selectInput("grade", "Grade",
                   c("All", sort(unique(all_flexitimes$Grade)))),
6. In the server file, I have changed the manual filters to:

   ## Optional: filter by Contract

   if (input$contract != "All") {

   ## contract <- paste0("%", input$contract, "%")

   m <- m %>% filter(Contract == input$contract)
   }

   ## Optional: filter by Grade

   if (input$grade != "All") {
   grade <- paste0("%", input$grade, "%")
   m <- m %>% filter(Grade == input$grade)
   }

   ## Optional: filter by Number

   if (!is.null(input$number) && input$number != "") {
     number <- paste0("%", input$number, "%")
     m <- m %>% filter(Number == input$number)
   }

   ## Optional: filter by Last Name

   if (!is.null(input$last) && input$last != "") {
     last <- paste0("%", input$last, "%")
     m <- m %>% filter(Last == input$last)